# How to get an attribute within an Element ID

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I have the following XML data. I would like to get the lat & lng values that only pertain to the location, not the southwest. How can I do this without having to also read the southwest.

```
 `<geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.5739894</lat>
    <lng>-0.1499698</lng>
   </location>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.5727314</lat>
     <lng>-0.1511809</lng>
    </southwest>
</geometry>`
```

So far, I've tried:
`

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes){
        if(localName.equals("location")){
            Node n1 = new Node(
                    Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue("lat"))
                    Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue("lng"))
            );
            current = n1;
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 2):

If your xml is not huge, its ok if you use an approach using `XPathFactory`. Otherwise go for SAX parser. But you need to do extra processing when writing SAX parsers particularly when you ahve conditions like I want only `location`'s `lat` value.

I would use an xpath approach, very simple to use, no need to use third party. It can be done via java.xml.*

Code would be :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse( new File( ".//input.xml" ) );

XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

XPathExpression latExpr = xpath.compile( "//location/lat" );
XPathExpression lngExpr = xpath.compile( "//location/lng" );

Object exprEval = latExpr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER );
if ( exprEval != null )
{
    System.out.println( "Location's lat value is :" + exprEval );
}
exprEval = lngExpr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER );
if ( exprEval != null )  
{
   System.out.println( "Location's lng value is :" + exprEval );
}
```

`input.xml` contains your xml.
It uses the xpath : `//location/lat` which means get me the value of `lat` whose parent is `location`.
And evaluate the xpath as a `NUMBER`.

Output is :

```
Location's lat value is :51.5739894
Location's lng value is :-0.1499698
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very interesting answer

Comment: @AnthonyJ If you find the answer useful, consider upvoting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, if I were you I'll use `org.json` parse as JSONObject to query every node.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
String lat = jsonObject.getString("lat");
String lng = jsonObject.getString("lng");
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used the Json parser but I'll give it a go.